# how to split order in two different child node in firebase android studio like Bar and kitchen counter send order two different counter

Tags: java, android

i am develop restaurant app problem is that two counter is there like bar and kitchen whenever customer send order item then split order different bar and kitchen separated by items how to do that in android application please any suggestion

nothing  any code for this concept

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be to define two sets of string-arrays in your strings.xml file like:

```
<string-array name="bar">
    <item>drink_1</item>
    <item>drink_2</item>
    <item>drink_3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="kitchen">
    <item>food_1</item>
    <item>food_2</item>
    <item>food_3</item>
</string-array>
```

Then for each item on the users order you could check in your activity if it exists in either of these string arrays:

```
String[] bar = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.bar);
String[] kitchen = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.kitchen);

if (Arrays.asList(bar).contains("First item in user order e.g drink1") {
    // found a match in bar, send to bar
} else if (Arrays.asList(kitchen).contains("First item in user order e.g drink1") {
    // found a match to kitchen, send to kitchen
} else {
    // does not match
}
```